# how to check if a file is currently open

Tags: google-apps-script

For a time recording application I am consolidating many time sheets based on Google Spreadsheets into one big time sheet to run statistics.

Everything runs just fine, but today I found out, that a consolidation error happened because a user was editing his time sheet right at the moment, when the consolidation process run.

How can I find out, if a user has currently opened his time sheet?

Any ideas?

Thanks Heinz

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_lockservice) to seek and lock your spreadsheet object before working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocsList services to get the last updated time which you can use to avoid the error due to the edit right at the time of consolidation.

e.g

```
var lastUpdateTime = DocsList.getFileById('FileID').getLastUpdated();
```

Comment: Thanks Wagar, I thoght about that one, but was hoping that there is a better way to do it. I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot.